# Azure WebJobs - How to disable adaptive sampling for application insights?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-webjobs

I came across [this MSDN article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/sampling) on configuring AppInsights sampling for various types of apps.

However I could not find a way to configure it for azure webjobs.

When it comes to configuring appinsights for the WebJob it would look something like this ([MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-sdk-get-started)):

```
static async Task Main()
{
    var builder = new HostBuilder();
    builder.UseEnvironment(EnvironmentName.Development);
    builder.ConfigureWebJobs(b =>
            {
                b.AddAzureStorageCoreServices();
                b.AddAzureStorage();
            });
    builder.ConfigureLogging((context, b) =>
            {
                b.AddConsole();

                // If the key exists in settings, use it to enable Application Insights.
                string instrumentationKey = context.Configuration["APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY"];
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(instrumentationKey))
                {
                    b.AddApplicationInsightsWebJobs(o => o.InstrumentationKey = instrumentationKey);
                }
            });
    var host = builder.Build();
    using (host)
    {
        await host.RunAsync();
    }
}
```

The relevant code is:

`b.AddApplicationInsightsWebJobs(o => o.InstrumentationKey = instrumentationKey);`

The options itself is as follows:

[image]

### Is it possible to disable adaptive sampling?

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest way is to set the `SamplingSettings` property to `null`:

```cs
.ConfigureLogging((loggingContext, builder) =>
{
    builder.AddConsole();
    builder.AddApplicationInsightsWebJobs(o =>
    {
        o.SamplingSettings = null;
    });
})
```

This prevents the `AdaptiveSamplingTelemetryProcessor` being added to the list of telemetry processors.

You can inspect whether adaptive sampling is active or not by taking a look at the `TelemetryClient.TelemetryConfiguration.TelemetryProcessors` property to see whether it contains an entry of type `AdaptiveSamplingTelemetryProcessor` or not.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to disable adaptive sampling?

You can disable Adaptive Sampling by going into the
**ApplicationInsights.config** file,  and remove or comment  the **AdaptiveSamplingTelemetryProcessor** node.

```xml
<TelemetryProcessors>

<!-- Disable adaptive sampling:
  <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel.AdaptiveSamplingTelemetryProcessor, Microsoft.AI.ServerTelemetryChannel">
    <MaxTelemetryItemsPerSecond>5</MaxTelemetryItemsPerSecond>
  </Add>
-->
```

Comment: That does not work for .Net Core as there is no .config file anymore.